# How to get values from multiple tables in php and mysql

Tags: php, sql

Hi guys i have 3 tables that stored my data and i want to get data from them but my written code not work please can someone tell me how i can do that?

my first table is "permission" that permission names and id included here.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `permission` (
`permission_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`permission_description` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

second table is "role" that included role names with roles id.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`role_group` int(11) NOT NULL,
`role_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`role_description` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and third "role_permission" included what permissions in "permission" table can access to what role in "role" table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role_permission` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`role_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`permission_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

PHP:

```
$result3 = $dp->sql_query("select p.*, r.*, a.* from role_permission p, role r, permission a WHERE p.role_id = r.id AND p.permission_id = a.permission_id");    
$rules = array();
while($rows3 = $dp->sql_fetchrow($result3))
        {
            $rules[] = array("title" => $rows3['permission_description'], // get value from "permission" table
                            "pages" => $row3['role_name'] . ", ",         // get value from "role" table
                            "pdes" => $row3['role_description']           // get value from "role" table
                     );
        }
 $smarty->assign("rules", $rules);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            {foreach $rules as $rule}
                <blockquote>
                    <p>
                        <strong>{$rule.title}:</strong>
                        <br>
                        <small>{$rule.pages}</small>
                    </p>
                </blockquote>
            {/foreach}
            </div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? No data, or wrong data?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: i added my html cod also, and the wrong thing is there is no result on my html page

Comment: Do you get the correct SELECT result if you run it directly against the db?

Comment: Does the SELECT return any data, when running MySQL Query Browser or whatever?

Comment: Yes look at this picture:   http://pasteboard.co/1ks8zvgR.png

Comment: OPS i found the problem ($row3 must be $rows3 ) But every result shows multiple time and its not true please see here : http://pasteboard.co/1ksIuMm0.png

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the same column `id` in the table `role` and `role_permission`. Array $rows3 will contain erroneous the same attribute `id`.
V.